# Как с помощью javascript узнать высоту, длину блока?

Tags: javascript

Как с помощью javascript узнать высоту, длину блока, а также задать ему с помощью javascript значение. Например, такой код

```
<table width='300' height='700'><tr><td></td></tr></table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Во первых тег `<table>` не имеент такого свойства как **height**, это на заметку!

Пример js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showMy()
{
    var td = document.getElementById("mytd");
    alert("height - " + td.getAttribute('height') + " | width - " + td.getAttribute('width'));
    //или можно
    td.innerHTML = "height - " + td.getAttribute('height') + " | width - " + td.getAttribute('width');
    //или можно много чего еще)
}
</script>

<table>
<tr>
<td width="300" height="700" id="mytd" onclick="showMy()">Скажи мне высоту!</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: а если этому блоку задана css высота

Comment: тогда не `td.getAttribute('height')` а `td.style.height`

Comment: или она увеличивается так как в нее набиваю контент

Comment: ок спс.....

Comment: Если увеличивается автоматически тогда `td.offsetHeight`

Короче говоря получить высоту и ширину можно как угодно!

Answer (score 3):

> тогда не td.getAttribute('height') а td.style.height

так высоту с ксс не узнаеш

нужно использовать getComputedStyle()
которая возвращает объект с значениями 
пример использования

```
var elemStyle = getComputedStyle(elem, null) || elem.currentStyle;
```

alert(elementStyle.marginTop)

Comment: Cтранно, почему же я узнал? Это магия наверное была, и браузер решил сжалиться надо мною и выдасть то что я от него хотел используя javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Узнать ширину блока можно, к примеру, так:

```
var b = document.getElementById("block");
var w = b.clientWidth || b.offsetWidth;
```

Высоту - так же, но с height.