# SVG. Определить размер текста

Tags: xml, svg, xsd

Возможно глупый вопрос, но задам. Можно ли как-то определить размер (height, width) который занимает текст в svg файле. Например, задан текст "Text1". 5 символов, font-family="Times New Roman", font-size="14pt". Нужно под этот текст запихнуть подложку какого-нибудь цвета.

Вариант с filter не совсем подходит, т.к. с его помощью можно просто задать фон текста (четко по границам), а мне бы хотелось, например, сделать этот фон побольше (т.е. вставить закрашенный прямоугольник).

Заранее вставить прямоугольник под текст тоже не вариант, я генерирую svg в зависимости от условий (т.е. текст может быть любой длины, любого шрифта и размера).

Каждый новый текст добавляется с следующим набором атрибутов:

```html
<text transform="translate(448,448)" fill="#000000" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="14pt">
  <tspan x="0" dy="0em">Text1</tspan> <!--для последующих строк с новой строки dy="1em"-->
</text>
```

Пример варианта с filter:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" baseProfile="full" height="100%" version="1.1" width="100%">
    <defs>
        <filter heighr="1" id="filter.00FF00" width="1" x="0" y="0">
            <feFlood flood-color="#00FF00"/>
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g id="root">
        <rect fill="#FFFFFF" height="1024" width="1024" x="0" y="0"/>
        <text transform="translate(128,256)" fill="#FF0000" font-family="Times New Roman" font-size="48pt" filter="url(#filter.00FF00)">
            <tspan x="0" dy="0em">Text1</tspan>
        </text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Это дает результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так же если, кто знает, почему xsd не хочет иметь дело с русским языком?
Есть элемент с атрибутом format. В XSD описан так:

```html
<xs:attribute name="format" use="optional">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="Числовой|Текстовый"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:attribute>
```

И если в xml документе есть элемент с атрибутом format="Текстовый" вылетает ошибка от парсера (python.lxml):

*:21:0:ERROR:SCHEMASV:SCHEMAV_CVC_DATATYPE_VALID_1_2_1: Element 'indicatorText', attribute 'format': 'Текстовый' is not a valid value of the local atomic type.*

Если заменить в XSD "Текстовый" на "text", а в xml документе format="Текстовый" на format="text" все работает.
Шапка XML:

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

Comment: Вам нужно определить размер текса в браузере через JavaScript? Если да, то могу ответить. Если нет, то SVG это масштабируемая графика, и размер любых элементов может зависеть от текущего SVG контейнера и масштабироваться при изменении размеров.

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин ну давайте по JS, может быть смогу выкрутится, я его использую для управления SVG.

Comment: Если у вас не браузер, то вряд-ли получится. Но вот ссылка на getComputedStyle - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/77125/205037 , позволяет узнать в браузере размеры отрендереного элемента.

Comment: Может эта ссылка и на не лучший ответ по `getComputedStyle`, но суть применять эту функцию, можете в интернете поискать для получения реальных размеров элемента

Comment: `heighr="1"` что это такое ?

Comment: @ДмитрийПолянин, спасибо.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, опечатка, не решает мою проблему, но вид текста после правки стал лучше (выделение текста стало ровно по границам, без нижнего лишнего куска как на рисунке), спасибо!